# Android - Selectable TextView inside a listview

Tags: android

I got a problem when trying to copy the content of TextView inside a listview on my Sony Xperia.

This is my listview:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

And this is my list_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my code:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_1);
     ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
     data.add("AAAAAAAAA");
     data.add("BBBBBBBBBB");
     data.add("CCCCCCCC");
     data.add("DDDDDDDDD");
     list.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(data));
}
```

This is my adapter:

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private ArrayList<String> mData;
    public MyAdapter (ArrayList<String> data){
        super();
        mData = data;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        String str = mData.get(position);
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tv.setText(str);
        tv.setTextIsSelectable(true);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I found on some threads that setTextIsSelectable(true) will allow copying text on TextView, but look like it's not work if TextView inside a listview.

Could you guys help me a solution?

Comment: A more manual implementation may help? Just set an onclicklistener on the textview and copy the text into clipboard via clipboard manager. Of course you need to set clickable of that textview to true

Comment: Thanks Chor, but I don't want to copy all the text, just a part of it like native copy/paste does

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put this on your TextView component: android:textIsSelectable="true"?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textIsSelectable="true"
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to put the code in the xml not in the java code and tell what happend. I tested and all was right

Comment: Did you test on Sony Xperia? I noticed that this issue only occurs on Sony Xperia, your code worked fine on other devices like Samsung Galaxy S3, HTC OneX